Customized OAuth2PasswordRequest form not working
replacing username with email in the OAuth2PasswordRequst form causes Authorizse form_data to result in the 422 Unprocessable data error
from fastapi import Depends, Form
from typing import Optional
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
from pydantic import Field


class OAuth2PasswordRequestFormWithIdentifier(OAuth2PasswordRequestForm):
    def __init__(
        self,
        grant_type: str = Form(default="password"),
        username: Optional[str] = Form(""),
        email: str = Form(...),
        password: str = Form(...),
        scope: str = Form(default=""),
        client_id: Optional[str] = Form(default=None),
        client_secret: Optional[str] = Form(default=None),
        identifier: Optional[str] = Form(default=None)
    ):
        username = email
        super().__init__(
            grant_type=grant_type,
            username=username,
            password=password,
            scope=scope,
            client_id=client_id,
            client_secret=client_secret
        )
        self.identifier = identifier

while this works using the endpoint shown below:
@router.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def user_login_for_access_token(
    form_data: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestFormWithIdentifier, Depends()],
    db: db_dependency,
):
    """Login user for an access token"""
    user = await authenticate_user(form_data.username, form_data.password, db)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Could not validate user. Incorrect email or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )

    tenant_identifier = form_data.identifier
    # tenant_identifier = ""
    token = create_access_token(
        user.email,
        user.id,
        tenant_identifier,
        timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    )

    return {'access_token': token, 'token_type': 'bearer'}

if I use OAuth2PasswordRequestFormWithIdentifier instead of OAuth2PasswordRequestForm then the below endpoint stops working:
@router.get("/", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def user(user: user_dependency, db: db_dependency):
    if user is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail='Authentication Failure')
    return {"Authenitcated User": user}


I added this function in the main.py:
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, status
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse, JSONResponse

@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    # Print the error details
    print(f"Error: {exc}")
    # Return the error details in the response
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
        content={"detail": exc.errors()},
    )

and it thrown this error:
Error: [{'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('body', 'email'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': None}]
So what I make out is because the Authorize form does not have email input box.


The body of the 422 error will tell you what information its complaining about in your request; you should add the error to your question.

Thanks @MatsLindh this is a great pointer, I was able to point the cause , however I dont know how can I add the email input box on the Authorize form I get from the fastapi docs page.

Ah, in that case - the OAuth2 standard says the field should be named username, and not email - so I'm not sure if you'll be able to change that if you want to remain compatible with the oauth2 spec. The FastAPI docs also says "And the spec says that the fields have to be named like that. So user-name or email wouldn't work. [...] But for the login path operation, we need to use these names to be compatible with the spec (and be able to, for example, use the integrated API documentation system)." - I don't think it's worth the trouble to change this.

I managed to keep the username username and work from Authorize form  you see in screenshot and endpoint supports email: str = Form(...)
